# The words that come always together in R

Tags: r, text-mining, word-frequency

I am using R  and there is a text column in my data set, and I need to know if there is any way to know what is the words are always come together.
like most two words come together or three words ...etc

For example:

```
Happy birthday to you 
Happy weekend 
Have a nice day
Be close 
Be smart 
Happy birthday 
It was a nice day
Happy birthday mama
```

So the results should be something like this

```
Happy birthday  - freq 3 
Nice day - freq 2
```

Comment: What means 'something like this' you probably need to be specific here.

Comment: What have you tried? Please create some sample code and even if it doesn't do a good job, paste it here and then we can improve it. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I don't know how will the result will be, but I mean I need something can show me the two words and how many times have been repeated in the columns.

Comment: I tried `ngram` function but I am not sure if it fits with what I need, so I am asking here to know your opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you need is to create bi-grams and count the features. Here is a way to do with `quanteda`.

```r
library(quanteda) 
text <- c("Happy birthday to you ", "Happy weekend ", "Have a nice day", 
          "Be close ", "Be smart ", "Happy birthday ", "It was a nice day", 
          "Happy birthday mama")
text %>% tokens() %>% 
  tokens_ngrams(n = 2, concatenator = " ") %>% dfm() %>% topfeatures()

## happy birthday         a nice       nice day    birthday to         to you       be smart 
##              3              2              2              1              1              1 
##  happy weekend         it was          was a         have a 
##              1              1              1              1
```

What it does is:

1. Tokenize
2. Create bigrams (concatenated with a single white space)
3. Create a document future matrix (as `topfeatures` requires it)
4. Count the most frequent features

Comment: thank you, is there any other function like `topfeatures()` ?